# Force Spring Reflection Util to use CGLIB

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-test

Just wondering if there is a way to force Spring's ReflectionTestUtils to use CGLIB instead of JDK proxies. 
**Note :** I'm just using the reflection utils to for writing tests and am not using an Application Context.

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] before posting a question

Comment: @Aleksej Can you please elaborate on your comment? Rereading the docs you're linking at, imho the question is okay (not superb alas, cause it is kind of artificial ...). But compared to all the other questions I review it is in the top 2% ;-).

Comment: @Hille: SO is intended to solve specific questions, so questions like "how to" are not usually welcome. The idea is to avoid that SO could be an how-to site, encouraging users to try something before posting, so that a question could provide attempts, search results, problems found. Here I only see an how-to request, no more, so I believe that the OP could improve the question. I agree with you, there are tons of questions much worst than this; I usually comment when I see an hope to improve the question, and vote to close when I see no hope at all; but it's of course only my point of view.

Comment: @Aleksej: Thanks for taking the time to answer; sorry for writing this comment (instead of just upvoting, but I wanted to document that it was me upvoting :-))

Comment: @Hille: No problem at all, no need to be sorry :). Upvoting, discussing, explaining, all well done!